# How can I remove the hardcoded menus from the Navin subtheme?

Tags: routes

I'm using [Navin](https://drupal.org/project/navin), a subtheme of Omega. I'm trying to hide the main menu, so that I can add a superfish menu, but I don't know where it's been hardcoded. It's not in a block (**admin/structure/blocks**). I've checked the theme settings page (**admin/appearance/settings/theme_name**) The `region--menu.tpl.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
  $main_links = menu_tree_page_data(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
  $main_links = menu_tree_output($main_links);
  $secondary_links = menu_tree_page_data(variable_get('menu_secondary_links_source', 'user-menu'));
  $secondary_links = menu_tree_output($secondary_links);
?>
<div<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php if ($main_links): ?>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <?php print render($main_links); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($secondary_links): ?>
    <nav class="navigation-secondary">
      <?php print render($secondary_links); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  $main_links = menu_tree_page_data(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
  $main_links = menu_tree_output($main_links);
  $secondary_links = menu_tree_page_data(variable_get('menu_secondary_links_source', 'user-menu'));
  $secondary_links = menu_tree_output($secondary_links);
?>
```

Get rid of that bit for starters.

If you're not using that, then you can probably also strip out the following:

```
<?php if ($main_links): ?>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <?php print render($main_links); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($secondary_links): ?>
    <nav class="navigation-secondary">
      <?php print render($secondary_links); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Which (for reference) should just leave you with the following:

```
<div<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was the trick - thanks. What did those 4 lines do that locked the menu in? What are the `$main_links` and `$secondary_links` variables?

Comment: Best explanation is the documentation: [`menu_tree_page_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_page_data/7), [`menu_tree_output`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/7). But basically, the first function says "Get the menu data for menu x", and then the second part says "Cool, thanks for that - time to make it look like a menu ready to put on the screen".

Answer (score 0):

Go here: /admin/appearance/settings/THEME

uncheck main menu

Comment: I tried that - I put the wrong link in the post

Thanks anyway

Comment: did you clear the cache after you disabled the menu?

Comment: I did do that - still no dice